# React js Nested route forces useEffect with empty array ([]) to rerun after it has been mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { Route, Switch, useLocation, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

//components
import PatientSidebar from './PatientSidebar';
import PatientData from './PatientData';

//redux
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getAllPatients } from '../../store/actions';

const Patient = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const location = useLocation();
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch(); // location={location} key={location.pathname}
  console.log(location);
  const [barWidth, setBarWidth] = useState();
  const [prevent, setPrevent] = useState('');


  /*This useEffect run when component is first mounted and it again runs when i select patient from sidebar (code is given below) to open its data using Link and nested routing*/
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllPatients());
  }, [dispatch]);

  document.title = 'Patients';
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        className='page-content ps-0 ps-md-3'
        style={{
          paddingLeft: '0',
          paddingTop: '70px',
          paddingRight: '0',
          // paddingBottom: '60px',
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}
      >
        <Row>
          <Col
            xs={12}
            lg={3}
            style={{ paddingRight: '0', width: `${barWidth}px` }}
            className='position-relative toggle-patient-bar ps-0'
          >
            <PatientSidebar setBarWidth={setBarWidth} />
          </Col>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              render={() => <PatientData barWidth={barWidth}/>}
              exact
              path={`/patient/:id`}
              strict
            />
          </Switch>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Patient;
```

I have this parent page with nested routing. The problem is when I click on patient to open its data in UI using `react-router-dom` (`Link`) it forces to remount this parent component which in result also forces to rerun `useEffect` which I really don't want to happen here.

NOTE: IT ONLY OCCURS ON PATIENT WHICH IS SELECTED FIRST TIME AFTER THAT IF I LOAD ANOTHER PATIENT IT DOESN'T RE MOUNT PARENT COMPONENT AND EVERYTHING WORKS FINE AS EXPECTED.

HERE IS THE SIDE BARCODE OF ALL PATIENTS:-
Here I posted the code of sidebar, if I click on patient to loaded it on nested Route.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Button, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, TabContent, TabPane } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router-dom';
import classnames from 'classnames';

//redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { showPatient, clearBills, loadMorePatients } from '../../store/actions';

//view hook
import useView from '../../Components/Hooks/UseView';

//loader
import Loader from '../../Components/Common/Loader';
import LoadMore from '../../Components/Common/LoadMore';

// let patients = ['Smith', 'Jack', 'Rose'];

const PatientSidebar = ({ setBarWidth }) => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  //search name
  const patient = useSelector((state) => state.viewPatient.patient);
  //get all patients
  const patients = useSelector((state) => state.getPatients.patients);
  //call redux action
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // Custom Tabs Bordered
  const [tHeight, setTHeight] = useState();
  const [customActiveTab, setcustomActiveTab] = useState('1');

  const toggleCustom = (tab) => {
    if (customActiveTab !== tab) {
      setcustomActiveTab(tab);
    }
  };

  const bar = useRef();
  const topRef = useRef();
  const headRef = useRef();
  const navsRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) setBarWidth(bar.current.clientWidth); //1200
    setTHeight(
      parseInt(topRef.current.clientHeight) +
        parseInt(headRef.current.clientHeight) +
        parseInt(navsRef.current.clientHeight)
    );
  }, [window.innerWidth]);

  const toogleTab = () => {
    var windowSize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    if (windowSize < 1300) {
      document.documentElement.getAttribute('toogle-patient-tab') === 'sm'
        ? document.documentElement.setAttribute('toogle-patient-tab', 'lg')
        : document.documentElement.setAttribute('toogle-patient-tab', 'sm');
    }
  };

  const getPatient = (item) => {
    if (patient && patient._id !== item._id) {
      dispatch(clearBills());
      dispatch(showPatient(item));
    } else {
      dispatch(showPatient(item));
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        ref={bar}
        className='patient-sidebar fancy-bar p-2 pt-3 position-fixed'
      >
        <div
          ref={topRef}
          className='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mt-2 mt-xl-0'
        >
          <h5 className='font-size-25 font-thin margin-bottom-0'>Patients</h5>
          <div className='d-flex'>
            <Button className='font-size-14 h-auto font-thin btn-primary btn-sm p-2 pt-1 pb-1'>
              Learn
            </Button>
            <div className='d-flex patient-menu-btn'>
              <button
                onClick={toogleTab}
                style={{ height: 'auto' }}
                type='button'
                className='btn btn-sm px-3 fs-16 header-item topnav-hamburger'
                id='topnav-hamburger-icon'
              >
                <span className='hamburger-icon'>
                  <span className='bg-dark'></span>
                  <span className='bg-dark'></span>
                  <span className='bg-dark'></span>
                </span>
              </button>

              {/* <SearchOption /> */}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='toogle-patient-tab'>
          <h6 ref={headRef} className='font-size-14 font-thin mt-3'>
            Jagruti Rehabilitation Center - Taloja
          </h6>
          <div className='mt-3'>

            <TabContent}}
              activeTab={customActiveTab}
              className='text-muted'
            >
              <TabPane tabId='1' id='home1'>
                <div className='d-flex'>
                  <div className='flex-grow-1 ms-0'>
                    {(patients || []).map((item, idx) => {
                      return (
                        **<Link
                          to={`/patient/${item._id}`}
                          className='text-decoration-none text-secondary font-size-16'
                          key={item._id}
                        >
                          <div
                            key={idx}
                            style={{
                              borderColor:
                                patient && patient._id === item._id
                                  ? '#1e90ff'
                                  : '',
                            }}
                            className='p-2 patients border-bottom-1 d-flex align-items-center'
                            onClick={() => {
                              getPatient(item);
                              toogleTab();
                            }}
                          >
                            <img
                              className='rounded-circle avatar-xxs header-profile-user me-3 mt-0'
                              src={item.avatar}
                              alt='Patient Avatar'
                            />
                            <h3 className='text-decoration-none text-capitalize mb-0 text-secondary font-size-14'>
                              {item.firstName}
                            </h3>
                          </div>
                        </Link>**
                      );
                    })}
                    {!patients && (
                      <div className='text-center'>
                        <div
                          className='spinner-border text-primary me-3'
                          role='status'
                        >
                          <span className='visually-hidden'>Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    )}
                    {patients && <LoadMore patients={patients} />}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId='2'>
                <div className='d-flex'>
                  <div className='flex-grow-1 ms-0'></div>
                </div>
              </TabPane>
              <TabPane tabId='3'>
                <div className='d-flex'>
                  <div className='flex-grow-1 ms-0'></div>
                </div>
              </TabPane>
            </TabContent>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default PatientSidebar;
```

I tried different ways of preventing it like passing dependency array but I think its runs due the component remount so that really didn't work out.

Component where all the routes are imported and exported to index.js(root file where routes are rendered) using react lazy loading.

```
import React, { lazy } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

//Dashboard
const Dashboard = lazy(() => import('../pages/Dashboard'));

//Client
const ViewPatients = lazy(() => import('../pages/ViewPatients/ViewPatients'));
const EditPatient = lazy(() => import('../pages/EditPatient/EditPatient'));
const AddUser = lazy(() => import('../pages/User/AddUser'));
const ViewAllUsers = lazy(() => import('../pages/User/ViewUsers'));
const EditUser = lazy(() => import('../pages/User/EditUser'));
const UsersLog = lazy(() => import('../pages/ActivityLog/UsersLog'));
const PatientsLog = lazy(() => import('../pages/ActivityLog/PatientsLog'));
const PatientLog = lazy(() => import('../pages/Patient/PatientLog'));
const ViewPatient = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/Patient/ViewPatient/ViewPatient')
);
const Patient = lazy(() => import('../pages/Patient/Patient'));

//Reports
const Reports = lazy(() => import('../pages/Reports/Reports'));

//Quick Registration
const QuickRegistration = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/QuickRegistration/QuickRegistration')
);
const DetailRegistration = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/DetailRegistration/DetailRegistration')
);

//Authentication Inner pages
const ResetPassword = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/ResetPassword/ResetPassword')
);

//login
const Login = lazy(() => import('../pages/Authentication/Login'));
const ForgetPassword = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/Authentication/ForgetPassword')
);
const Logout = lazy(() => import('../pages/Authentication/Logout'));
const Register = lazy(() => import('../pages/Authentication/Register'));

// User Profile
const UserProfile = lazy(() => import('../pages/Authentication/user-profile'));
const Profile = lazy(() => import('../pages/Profile/Profile'));

// Settings
const AdvancePaymentSettings = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/AdvancePaymentSettings/AdvancePaymentSettings')
);
const InvoiceSettings = lazy(() =>
  import('../pages/InvoiceSettings/InvoiceSettings')
);
const Settings = lazy(() => import('../pages/Settings/Setting'));

const authProtectedRoutes = [
  { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/index', component: Dashboard },

  //Client
  // { path: '/add-patient', component: AddPatient },
  { path: '/view-patients', component: ViewPatients },
  { path: '/edit-patient', component: EditPatient },
  { path: '/add-user', component: AddUser },
  { path: '/view-users', component: ViewAllUsers },
  { path: '/edit-user', component: EditUser },
  { path: '/users-log', component: UsersLog },
  // { path: "/patients-log", component: PatientsLog },
  { path: '/patient-log', component: PatientLog },
  // { path: '/view-patient', component: ViewPatient },
  { path: '/user-profile', component: Profile },
  //page where this issues occures -------------- start
  { path: '/patient', component: Patient },
  { path: '/patient/:id', component: Patient },
  //page where this issues occures -------------- end
  { path: '/quick-registration', component: QuickRegistration },
  { path: '/detail-registration', component: DetailRegistration },
  { path: '/settings', component: Settings },
  { path: '/advance-payment-settings', component: AdvancePaymentSettings },
  { path: '/invoice-settings', component: InvoiceSettings },
  { path: '/reports', component: Reports },
  { path: '/reset-password', component: ResetPassword },

  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    component: () => <Redirect to='/login' />,
  },
];

const publicRoutes = [
  // Authentication Page
  { path: '/logout', component: Logout },
  { path: '/login', component: Login },
  { path: '/forgot-password', component: ForgetPassword },
  { path: '/register', component: Register },
];

export { authProtectedRoutes, publicRoutes };
```

Root index.js file of all the routes:

```
import React, { useEffect, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

//Layouts
import NonAuthLayout from '../Layouts/NonAuthLayout';
import VerticalLayout from '../Layouts/index';
//routes
import { authProtectedRoutes, publicRoutes } from './allRoutes';
import { AuthProtected, AccessRoute } from './AuthProtected';

//load user
import { loadUser } from '../store/auth/actions/auth';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import setAuthToken from '../utils/setAuthToken';

//import alerts
import Alerts from '../Components/Common/Alerts';

//loader
import Loader from '../Components/Common/LargeLoader';

// React Toastify
// import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
// import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const Index = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  const availablePublicRoutesPaths = publicRoutes.map((r) => r.path);
  const availableAuthRoutesPath = authProtectedRoutes.map((r) => r.path);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Alerts />
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={availablePublicRoutesPaths}>
            <NonAuthLayout>
              <Switch>
                {publicRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                  <Route
                    path={route.path}
                    component={route.component}
                    key={idx}
                    exact={true}
                  />
                ))}
              </Switch>
            </NonAuthLayout>
          </Route>

          <Route path={availableAuthRoutesPath}>
            {/* <AuthProtected> */}
            <VerticalLayout>
              <Switch>
                {authProtectedRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
                  <AccessRoute
                    path={route.path}
                    component={route.component}
                    key={idx}
                    exact={true}
                  />
                ))}
              </Switch>
            </VerticalLayout>
            {/* </AuthProtected> */}
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: What component is being remounted, and what/where/how is it rendered? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]?

Comment: Hello drew i have edit the post top code is where problem occurs which is the root component and below is the sidebar code

Comment: I don't see any `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array. Where and how is `Patient` component rendered? Can you also add the exact reproduction steps it takes to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hello Mr Drew thank you for helping me. I have edit the post now it includes from root file to file where the issue occur please check it out once you are free. Thank you : )

Comment: So is it the `Patient` component that is remounted? I see that it is rendered on two routes, `"/patient/:id"` and `"/patient"`. Is it when you navigate from `"/patient"` to `"/patient/:id"` after selecting a specific patient person that `Patient` component is remounted? It's a bit odd since `Patient` also renders a route on `"/patient/:id"` to render a `PatientData` component.

Comment: Yes Mr Drew it is the `Patient` page that is remounted. First when i nagivate to patient the `useEffect` runs like normal but when i selelect `patient` from the list in `sidebar` then the `useEffect` in `Patient` again runs. I think it is because i have rendered Patient component on two `Routes` but if i remove `/patient/:id` then the nested routing won't even works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've a few things working against you.

1. All the mapped routes specify the `exact` prop, so this is *why* removing the `"/patient/:id"` causes `Patient` to not render when that is the URL path.
2. The app is rendering `Patient` on two distinct paths that can only *exactly* match.

The `Patient` component is rendering another `"/patient/:id"` route as a descendent route, so there's no need really for `"/patient/:id"` to also be a root route rendering another `Patient` component. Something to keep in mind is that the `Switch` component renders the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` component. This means you should list the routes in the inverse order of route path specificity, i.e. `"/:company/employees/:id"` is more specific than `"/:company/employees` is more specific than `"/segment"` is more specific than `"/"`. An example configuration may look like the following:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:company/employees/:id" component={EmployeeDetail} />
  <Route path="/:company/employees" component={Employees} />
  <Route path="/:company" component={Company} />
  <Route path="/" exact component={Home} /> 
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

If a more specific path isn't matchable to the current URL path then the matching continues on to less specific paths. When ordered correctly there is nearly no need at all for the `exact` prop. `exact` is used in the above example to *exactly* match `"/"` for a home/landing page, but anything that wasn't already matched above it or by the home/landing page will be rendered by the final "catch-all" `NotFound` route, i.e. like a 404 page.

Another thing to consider in RRDv5 is that the path acts more like a "path prefix". This means that path `"/patient"` can match both `"/patient"` ***and*** `"/patient/:id"`. This means a root route `"/patient"` *acts* more like `"/patient*"`.

I recommend reordering the routes in the configuration arrays to be in "proper" path specificity order. If you need to exactly match any specific entry then specify the `exact` prop here like did with the `Redirect` to login route. The `path` prop can take an array of paths, so for the routes that render the same component you can use an array of paths to match. The order by specificity still matters within the array.

```
const authProtectedRoutes = [
  { path: ['/dashboard', '/index'], component: Dashboard },

  //Client
  { path: '/add-patient', component: AddPatient },
  { path: '/view-patients', component: ViewPatients },
  { path: '/edit-patient', component: EditPatient },
  { path: '/add-user', component: AddUser },
  { path: '/view-users', component: ViewAllUsers },
  { path: '/edit-user', component: EditUser },
  { path: '/users-log', component: UsersLog },
  { path: "/patients-log", component: PatientsLog },
  { path: '/patient-log', component: PatientLog },
  { path: '/view-patient', component: ViewPatient },
  { path: '/user-profile', component: Profile },

  { path: ['/patient/:id', '/patient'], component: Patient },

  { path: '/quick-registration', component: QuickRegistration },
  { path: '/detail-registration', component: DetailRegistration },
  { path: '/settings', component: Settings },
  { path: '/advance-payment-settings', component: AdvancePaymentSettings },
  { path: '/invoice-settings', component: InvoiceSettings },
  { path: '/reports', component: Reports },
  { path: '/reset-password', component: ResetPassword },

  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    render: () => <Redirect to='/login' />,
  },
];
```

```
// NOTE: flatMap flattens any nested arrays of paths
const availablePublicRoutesPaths = publicRoutes.flatMap((r) => r.path);
const availableAuthRoutesPath = authProtectedRoutes.flatMap((r) => r.path);

<Switch>
  <Route path={availablePublicRoutesPaths}>
    <NonAuthLayout>
      <Switch>
        {publicRoutes.map((route) => (
          <Route key={route.path} {...route} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </NonAuthLayout>
  </Route>

  <Route path={availableAuthRoutesPath}>
    <VerticalLayout>
      <Switch>
        {authProtectedRoutes.map((route, idx) => (
          <AccessRoute key={route.path} {...route} />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </VerticalLayout>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```